# Noob needs help with generics

Tags: vb.net, generics

Could you please review my code below, noting the 3 places where an error message is returned and suggest a fix? The error commented out is to the right of the offending line

Thanks!

```
Public Interface IIdentity

    Property Identity As Integer

End Interface


Public Class IdentityCollection(Of T As IIdentity)

    'Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of T)
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of Integer, T)

    Public Function ItemByPrimaryKey(identity As Integer) As T

        For Each currentItem As T In Me 'Error  1   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Integer, T)' cannot be converted to 'T'.  d:\users\chad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Class2.vb   18  38  WindowsApplication4
            If currentItem.Key = identity Then 'Error   2   'Key' is not a member of 'T'.   d:\users\chad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Class2.vb   19  16  WindowsApplication4
                Return T
            End If
        Next
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function ItemByPrimaryKeySecondApproach(identity As Integer) As T
        Return (From X In Me Select X Where X.Key = identity).FirstOrDefault 'Error 4   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair(Of Integer, T)' cannot be converted to 'T'.  d:\users\chad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Class2.vb   27  16  WindowsApplication4
    End Function


    Public Shadows Sub Add(item As T)
        MyBase.Add(item.Identity, item)
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Customer

    Implements IIdentity

    Public Sub New(customerKey As Integer, lastName As String, firstname As String)
        _CustomerKey = customerKey
        _LastName = lastName
        _FirstName = firstname
    End Sub

    Private _CustomerKey As Integer

    Public Property CustomerKey As Integer Implements IIdentity.Identity
        Get
            Return _CustomerKey
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _CustomerKey = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _LastName As String
    Public Property LastName() As String
        Get
            Return _LastName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _LastName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _FirstName As String
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return _FirstName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _FirstName = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class

Public Class CustomerCollection

    Inherits IdentityCollection(Of Customer)

End Class
```

Update:

I see that the Item function on the Dictionary collection object does what I want, but I'd still like to know why I am getting the errors noted above.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1:** When you enumerate through a Dictionary, each item is a KeyValuePair containing both Key (of type Integer in your case) and value (of type T in your case). So you should have:

```
For Each currentItem As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, T) In Me
```

**Error 2:** I think the error message is pretty clear, but if you do the change described above, this line will be OK. The Key property is part of the KeyValuePair class and gets the dictionary key.

**Error 3:** Same as error 1, when querying the dictionary the return type is KeyValuePair(Of Integer, T), not T. To retrieve the actual value (of type T), use the Value property of the KeyValuePair:

```
Return (From X In Me Where X.Key = identity Select X.Value).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: first 2 now are fixed. Error 3 is now: Error 1 Name 'X' is either not declared or not in the current scope. d:\users\chad\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication4\WindowsApplication4\Class2.vb 30 51 WindowsApplication4

Comment: You need to reverse the Where and Select statements, see my edited code.